# NoClassDefFoundError(HBaseConfiguration) while trying to create Hbase table from Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hiveql

I use a simple query in Hue.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table_2(key int, name string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:name")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "test");
```

I run into

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
```

I am running HDP 2.1 Sandbox. I tried to copy several libs. No luck so far. Changing env variables did not work as an Ambari restart resets the vars

Details

```
ERROR exec.DDLTask: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.setConf(HBaseStorageHandler.java:250)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getStorageHandler(HiveUtils.java:304)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getStorageHandler(Table.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4064)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:281)
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: what version of hadoop,hbase,hive are you using?

Comment: All that is in the HDP 2.1 ecosystem stack.

Answer (score 0):

I digged deeper and solved the problem on my own. The solution was on the HortonWorks webpage.

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.7/bk_releasenotes_hdp_2.1/content/ch_relnotes-hdpch_relnotes-hdp-2.1.3-knownissues-hue.html